# Convert object of type object {char[]} to char[]

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I use reflection to iterate over my object fields. To read a field value I use

`object elementValue = element.GetValue(value)`

because I don't know what kind of type I will get. My object has also a field of type char[]. When I read it using GetValue(value) I receive a variable of type object{char[]}. I would like to convert it into char[]. But how can I do it? I cannot iterate over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
char[] array = (char[])elementValue;
```

`{char[]}` is not a type. Debugger displays it for convenience. It is actually `char[]` only. So just a cast is enough.

For example following code will be displayed as `{string[]}` in debugger.

```
object elementValue = new string[] { "asdfasd" };
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
char[] arr = (char[])elementValue;
```